# Чат client-server на java

Tags: java

У меня есть простенький чат написанный на java. Сервер для него я запустил на линуксе, а клиент подключается с компьютера на windows.Если вводить локальный ip для подключения к  ServerSocket , то все работает, но если я пытаюсь подключиться через интернет, используя внешний ip и другой компьютер -- подключение не проходит. (на сервере еще лежит сайт, который можно открыть через внешний ip). Скажите, возможно ли вообще подключиться к такому чату через интернет?

Comment: С каким параметров вы сокет открывали на сервере? Я могу ошибаться, но если указать как localhost, то сервер не буден видет в сети. Нужно создавать используя пустой конструктор

Comment: Если локально чат через сокет нормально работает, а на удаленном сервере нет - скорее всего, не получается установить соединение с `serverIp:serverPort`. Может, нет сети, может, блокирует брандмауэр (входящее соединение или сам серверный сокет) - это уже надо смотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас на роутере должны быть порты проброшены на сервер с чатом.
Про проброс портов можно почитать здесь:
http://www.dlink.ru/u/faq/246/1156.html

Comment: Добавил переадресацию в роутере и все заработало!